# cocos2d-x how to play background music on android

Tags: android, cocos2d-x

I know if the music file under the 'Resources', it can work well.
But now, the music file under the '/data/' directory. It cant't play! why?

Comment: code? what have you tried?

Comment: By default, cocos2d-x read everything ONLY from Resources folder. inside the build_native.sh it copy everything from resrouces folder to  assets folder of you android porject. if you want other resources been added to you app, you can manually copy those to the android assets folder.

Comment: thank you! But the music file from server. When start the game, user first get music file from the server to the local directory '/data/...'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access via absolute path, example: /data/data/your.package.name/files/music.mp3